# Should I remove my post or should I give my solution there?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, self-answer

I've just asked something here:
[Can't connect to a Oracle db instance via SQLDeveloper](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76348/cant-connect-to-a-oracle-db-instance-via-sqldeveloper)

In the meantime I figured it out myself, so I don't know what is the proper process at times like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, please give your solution! Post it as an answer to your own question – you're allowed to do that – and accept the answer. (Please don't edit it into the question itself.)

That way other people in the future with the same issue can google it and find a solution - yours.

Comment: Thank you, I will update.

Comment: @Pista Be sure to post the solution as an "answer". Don't edit the question and post it there. Otherwise the question will remain "unanswered" even though there is a solution.

Comment: Agreed. I've answered a few of my own questions after trial and error, and I continue to received rep points for upvotes from others that found the solution useful. Everyone wins!